# Call server side python script from webpage

Tags: jquery, python-2.7, asynchronous, web, raspberry-pi

I am a hobbyist and have learnt most of what i know about coding by trawling these forums.

I have a network of Raspberry Pi computers that are programmed to take a photo when the server sends a multicast message. this is all working and implemented in Python.

I would like to setup a webpage to act as a GUI to send the multicast message including some parameters which are passed to the python script when it is executed. I would be happy for a button which launched the script and go from there.

I have setup apache and have been able to launch php and python simple scripts directly.

The scripts that i have created so far are only 'hello world' style scripts, anything more than printing to html seems to fail without any feedback 
So far i have been searching for a few weeks, i have done tutorials for HTML CSS Javascript and Jquery and am no closer. I have also considered running the whole thing from a python web framework but didnt have much luck with that either.
Ideally, i would like to have a webpage that can run a script when the buttons are pressed.

I understand that this is probably too many words with out any code but i am quite lost at the moment. It seems like a task that i should be able to find tutorials for but i have had no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please structure your question by adding some paragraphs? It is *very* hard to read and understand.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19331969/running-system-calls-from-webserver
: Another rapsberry user did something similar

Comment: Thanks for your help but how do I do that without. Navigating away from the page?

Answer (score 2):

A web framework is the best way to approach this. Take a look at [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/). It's a very lightweight and has good tutorials.

Start by installing flask. Id recommend installing in a virtual env.

Then create an app something like this:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return '''
<html>
  <a class="btn" href="/takephoto">Take Photo</a>
</html>
'''

@app.route('/takephoto')
def take_photo():
    # Run code or function for taking photo here
    return 'Photo Taken'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```